# ReactiveUI View Bindings to attached property

Tags: reactiveui

[This Blog Entry](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2012/08/27/reactiveui-4-0-preview-2-is-here/) describes using View Bindings as a replacement for XAML Bindings. I like the convention-based wire-up:

```
this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.FooMirror);
```

And if I want to bind to a TextBox's Text property:

```
this.Bind(ViewModel, x => x.SomeText, x => x.SomeText.Text);
```

However I have an attached property which I would like to bind to (for an implementation of the [attached behaviour pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johngossman/archive/2008/05/07/the-attached-behavior-pattern.aspx)). How do I use the View Bindings syntax to bind to an attached property?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Binding doesn't know anything about XAML attached properties at the moment - you might have to work around this by doing something like:

```
this.WhenAny(x => x.ViewModel.SomeCoolProperty, x => x.Value)
    .Subscribe(x => theControl.SetValue(AttachedObject.MyAttachedProperty, x);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd figured this one out. I was wondering if I'd missed a more 'ReactiveUI' way of doing it.  It's a OneWayBind which suits my needs, but wouldn't work if a two way bind was required.

Comment: Theoretically you could make this work but you need a way to provide the DependencyProperty object which doesn't exist in the current API because it's not tied to XAML

Comment: The OP is exactly my problem but this answer and comments are too vague for me to figure out.  Specifically the .Subscribe statement I can't figure out. What do I do with that?  I guess I need more sample code