# How to bind ReactiveList<SomeObject> to WPF ListBox or ListView?

Tags: reactiveui

I have a simple ViewModel:

```
public class SampleCollectionViewModel : ReactiveObject
    {
        public SampleCollectionViewModel()
        {
            this.Countries = new ReactiveList<Country>();
            this.Countries.Add(new Country { Name = "Andora" });
            this.Countries.Add(new Country { Name = "Aruba" });
            this.Countries.Add(new Country { Name = "Afganistan" });
            this.Countries.Add(new Country { Name = "Algeria" });
            this.Countries.Add(new Country { Name = "Argentina" });
            this.Countries.Add(new Country { Name = "Armenia" });
            this.Countries.Add(new Country { Name = "Antigua" });    
            //CountryNames.AddRange(this.Countries.Select(x => x.Name));
        }

        public ReactiveList<Country> Countries { get; set; }
        //public ReactiveList<string> CountryNames { get; set; }
    }
```

and a simple View:

```
public partial class SampleCollectionWindow : Window, IViewFor<SampleCollectionViewModel>
    {
        public SampleCollectionWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.ViewModel = new SampleCollectionViewModel();


            this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Countries, v => v.CountriesListBox.ItemsSource);
        }

        public SampleCollectionViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

        object IViewFor.ViewModel
        {
            get { return ViewModel; }
            set { ViewModel = (SampleCollectionViewModel)value; }
        }
    }
```

When I run it I get:
 ``` exception Additional information: Can't two-way convert between ReactiveUI.ReactiveList``1[DemoReactiveUiWpf.SampleCollection.Country] and System.Collections.IEnumerable. To fix this, register a IBindingTypeConverter ```

If I change 
`this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Countries, v => v.CountriesListBox.ItemsSource);`
to
`this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Countries, v => v.CountriesListBox.ItemsSource);`
nothing happens with ListBox

Later I'm going to expand this simple demo to have a command and async command to add new country to the model.

Remove selected in `ListBox` / `ListView` items.

Try filtering, sorting and other interesting operations that ReactiveUI offers.

But as for now I just can't do simple binding...

How to bind `ListBox` / `ListView` to `ReactiveList<Country>` and do common operations with ReactiveList + ListBox/ListView in the right way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You definitely cannot use a two-way binding to bind to ItemsSource - as the error message says, you can't guarantee that someone setting `ListBox.ItemsSource` will use a `ReactiveList<Country>`. This works on my machine:

```
this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.Countries, x => x.countries.ItemsSource);
```

> ...nothing happens with ListBox

I wonder if you perhaps didn't configure a DataTemplate? ReactiveUI overrides default DataTemplates with one that uses `ViewModelViewHost` (and since you most likely don't have a View registered for Country, it would fail).

**Update:** Here's how I'd bind SelectedItems, put this in the View:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.countries.SelectedItems)
    .Select(list => list.Cast<Country>())
    .BindTo(this, x => x.ViewModel.SelectedCountries);
```

Comment: OneWayBind works fine. In my case my bad was that ViewModel has not been initialized. What is the difference between `this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Countries, v => v.CountriesListBox.ItemsSource);` and `this.WhenAny(x => x.ViewModel.Countries, x => x.Value).Subscribe(x => CountriesListBox.ItemsSource = x);` suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275141/reactiveui-view-bindings-to-attached-property?rq=1 when to use the approach with WhileAny?

Comment: Hm.. but now a bit different question regarding the same code: How to get selected items from CountriesListBox? If I understand correctly selected ListBox items should bind to `ReactiveList<string> SelectedCountries;` somehow. Is it correct? If yes - how to define it with ReactiveUI? It's a bit hard to find examples of it.

Comment: If you want to bind to SelectedItems, you have to do it yourself

Comment: @PaulBetts Regarding your update on how to bind to selected items, it doesn't work for me. Shouldn't there be a converter from IEnumerable to ReactiveList for binding to work?